# concatenar parametros javascript

Tags: javascript, string

una pregunta, como puedo escribir una funcion llamada escribirCartelito, y que me tome los parametros y los una en una sola string?, no puedo usar concat...y asi como esta me dice que no defini el parametro titulo..pero ya no se como modificarlo

```
function escribirCartelito(titulo, nombre, apellido){
  return (titulo, nombre, apellido);
}
escribirCartelito( "Dr", "juan", "perez");
console.log(escribirCartelito(titulo+nombre+apellido));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa [Plantilla de cadena de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings), creo que es la opción más fácil y legible:

```js
function escribirCartelito(titulo, nombre, apellido){
  return `${titulo} ${nombre} ${apellido}`;
}
console.log(escribirCartelito( "Dr", "juan", "perez"));
```

También se puede hacer que devuelva un arreglo y unir las partes con `.join()` para mostrar solo la cadena o seguir usando el arreglo para otros fines:

```js
function escribirCartelito2(titulo, nombre, apellido){
  return [titulo, nombre, apellido];
}
console.log(escribirCartelito2( "Dr", "juan", "perez").join(' '));
```

Comment: Bonita opcion, me gustan las plantillas de cadena de texto (template literals) me parecen super bonitas :3, pero eso dejaría sin poder reusar directamente nuestros parametros luego (habria que hacer un proceso para poder tener de nuevo nuestros parametros).

Comment: Pero solo quiere concatenar :-)

Comment: Bueno... eso es cierto, te doy mi voto arriba, me gusta tu opcion :v

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que crees que `return` tiene el poder de devolverte varios valores, lo cual no es cierto, return solo puede devolverte un solo valor, asi que partimos de ahi, en tu caso puedes hacer lo siguiente para resolver tu problema:

```js
function escribirCartelito(titulo, nombre, apellido){
  return [titulo, nombre, apellido];
}
console.log(...escribirCartelito("Dr", "juan", "perez"));
```

Lo que hicimos fue encerrar tus valores dentro de un `arreglo` para que pudieses devolver varios valores:

```
return [titulo, nombre, apellido];
```

Tambien a cartelito, como devuelve un arreglo podemos usar el operador rest (...) para poder que nos devuelva el titulo, el nombre y el apellido en ese orden y poder imprimirlo directamente:

```
console.log(...escribirCartelito("Dr", "juan", "perez"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Puntos a mencionar:

- Así como tienes la instrucción `return` generaría que solo te devuelva el último valor ingresado que sería el apellido, **entonces deberás concatenar por ejemplo con el símbolo de *+* para que a los 3 parámetros los tome como uno y en concencuencia te los retorne en conjunto y no solo el último**
- La función tiene 3 parámetros por lo cual cuando la invocas deberás pasar 3 argumentos (cosa que si estás haciendo) pero el fallo es que la mandas a imprimir mencionando de nuevo a los parámetros lo cual no es correcto

Debería ser así:

```js
    function escribirCartelito(titulo, nombre, apellido){
      return (titulo+" "+nombre+" "+apellido);
    }
    console.log(escribirCartelito( "Dr", "juan", "perez"))
```

Entonces observamos que de la forma en que tienes tu código:

- Construyes la función indicando la cantidad de parámetros para que esta de forma interna los procese haciendo con ellos algo
- Cuando la invocas deberás simplemente en los paréntesis pasar la misma cantidad de valores que se supone la función espera
- No es necesario que la invoques por segunda vez mencionando los parámetros declarados mas arriba

**Lecturas recomendadas**

- [return sintax](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/return)

Answer (score 1):

La llamada `escribirCartelito( "Dr", "juan", "perez");` no es necesaria. Esto simplemente te devuelve los parámetros concatenados pero no los estás visualizando en ningún lado.
Tendrías que pasar los parámetros correctos a la función cuando la llamas desde el console.log.

El código quedaría así:

```js
function escribirCartelito(titulo, nombre, apellido){
  return (titulo + " " + nombre + " "+ apellido);
}
console.log(escribirCartelito("Dr", "juan", "perez"));
```

Comment: Justamente pensaba lo mismo... esa llamada a escribirCartelito es innecesaria...

Answer (score 0):

Sustituye las comas por el símbolo más (+) al crear la función:

```
function escribirCartelito(titulo, nombre, apellido){
  return (titulo + nombre + apellido);
}
```